# Redis keys function for match with multiple pattern

Tags: redis, nosql, key, database-scan

How can I find keys with multiple match pattern, for example I have keys with

```
foo:*, event:*, poi:* and article:* patterns.
```

How can I find keys with redis keys function for match with foo:* or poi:* pattern, its like

```
find all keys with prefix foo:* or poi:*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do this. KEYS is mainly a debug command. It is not supposed to be used for anything else.

Redis is not a database supporting ad-hoc queries: you are supposed to provide access paths for the data you put into Redis (using extra set or hash or zset indexes).

If you really need to run arbitrary boolean expressions on keys to select data, I would suggest to do it offline by using the [rdb-redis-tools](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools) package.

Comment: I agree with Didier. Since redis 2.8, you can use [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan), which you can use for online scanning. However, that's not what you want your clients to use. Follow Didier's advice for that.

Comment: `SCAN cursor MATCH pattern COUNT count`
i.e.
`SCAN 0 MATCH user:* COUNT 1000`

check the docs for more specifics: https://redis.io/commands/scan

Comment: Keep in mind COUNT doesn't exactly mean what you may assume it does. Check the SCAN command docs mentioned above.