# How to get all redis keys by number range of prefix

Tags: regex, redis, prefix, redis-cli

I need to get all the keys by prefix of the range of 62-125 and followed by ':'

Iv'e tried running the following with no success:

`res = r.keys('[62-125]:*')`

Also tried using scan:

```
iter = r.scan_iter('^(6[2-9]|7[0-9]):*')
res = []

for key in iter:
    res.append(key)
```

Is this even possible? if yes how?

Some examples incase it's not clear:

Keys that should be retrieved:

```
62:kk:345345345
72:hg:76576
88:fg:67886
122:hg:8678
124:gg:8678
```

Keys that should NOT be retrieved:

```
0:df:09765
20:gg:6565
38:hh:345
44:bb:3454
61:bb:6568
```

All the keys in my DB are staring with a number prefix followed by ':' if it matter.

Answer (score 1):

Redis' patterns (for `KEYS` and `SCAN`) are glob-like so trying to use regex on them is a no-go.

You could use a server-side Lua script (with Lua having more robust pattern-matching capabilities, although not POSIX regex) that performs a full `SCAN` and filters the results.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29945372/3160475 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution:

```
RES = []

_res = r.keys('6[2-9]:*')
RES.append(_res)

for i in range(7,13):
    _res = r.keys('{}[0-9]:*'.format(i))
    RES.append(_res)
```

This works but i do NOT accept this answer.

1. It's disgusting and cause me self loathing
2. It's not efficient at all

I will vote down for my own solution if it was possible. Please suggest a better one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [REDIS PIPELINE](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining)

Like this...

```
Pipeline pipelined = jedis.pipelined();
for(keys : 62-125){
      pipelined.keys("keys*");
}
pipelined.sync();
for(Reponse response : responses){
      Object o = response.get(); //Here you get the list of keys
}
```

You can't use `KEYS` and `SCAN` to get keys for multiple match pattern.Refer this for more [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949147/redis-keys-function-for-match-with-multiple-pattern)